# Why are jqGrid fields hidden in form edit, even though "edithidden:true" is included in the colModel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.3.1, I have some columns which are hidden in grid view, but I would like them to be visible and editable in an edit form.

According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules), the `edithidden` sub-option of the `editrules` option of the `colModel` module enables the exact behaviour I desire (emphasis mine):

> This option is valid only in form editing module. By default the hidden fields are not editable. **If the field is hidden in the grid and edithidden is set to true, the field can be edited when add or edit methods are called.**

However, when I implement the following code:

```
{name:'AcmeCoValue',editrules: {edithidden: true}, editable: true, show:'AcmeCovalue', hidden:true, fixed:'true', width: 65},
```

the rendered HTML of the edit form shows this field as:

```
<tr style="display:none" rowpos="7" class="FormData" id="tr_RedCoValue">
```

which is the same behaviour I have when I set:

```
editrules: {edithidden: false}
```

which seems to me like the `edithidden` parameter is ineffective.

The only way I've found to make it visible is to force the field onto a visible row with the `formoptions:{rowpos:7}` option, which makes the field visible even when `edithidden: false`.

Why doesn't edithidden seem to have any effect?

This is legacy code which I inherited. Is there anything I should check, which might be overriding the expected behaviour of `edithidden`?

I think I can manually implement the behaviour I desire in Javascript but I would prefer to do it the "jqGrid" way for simplicity and maintainability, and I also worry about why it doesn't work, and what other problems might be related to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of

```
editrules: {edithidden: true}, editable: true, hidden: true
```

makes the column editable, but under "editable" one means that the data from the column will be sent to the server only. Because jqGrid send the data from the form to server it fill the form with hidden row, but the row stays hidden.

You can include `$("#tr_RedCoValue").show()` inside of `beforeShowForm` callback (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events)) to fix the problem.

In any way I would strictly recommend you to upgrade retro version 4.3.1, which you use to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.6, which you can use from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and [the get started documentation](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)). The version 4.3.1 was published more as 5 years ago. It was the time of Chrome 16, Firefox 8 and IE9. Now one uses Chrome 55, Firefox 50.1, Microsoft Edge 38, IE11. It's not difficult to understand, that jqGrid 4.3.1 can't work good in modern web browsers and with more recent versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will upgrading from 4.3.1 to 4.13.6 affect the behaviour of showing editable fields in form view but not in grid view, as you've desrcribed?

Comment: @StockB: You are welcome! You can easy test free jqGrid 4.13.6 by loading jqGrid CSS and JS files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). You will need modify only 3 lines of your HTML code. You will see that `editrules: {edithidden: true}, editable: true, hidden: true` will **display** and allow to edit the data in the form. Free jqGrid supports many other options like editable as callback or usage string value for `editable`: "hidden", "disabled" or "readonly". I can't explain the features of last 5 years.

Comment: It sounds like upgrading would save me this headache and many more. I'll try it in a test environment to check for compatibility.

Comment: Simply updating to 4.13.6 hasn't magically fixed the problem, so I suspect there may be some in-house CSS or JS affecting this behaviour. I'll give the `beforeShowForm` function a try when I have some time.

Comment: @StockB: It's better that you prepare **the demo**, which demonstrates the problem. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/edithidden-test.htm). It uses `hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, editable: true` in Notes and Total columns.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, Oleg. I'll need some time to deeply understand our implementation to see what might be interfering. Until then, thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: @StockB: You are welcome! You could prepare new demo in JSFiddle, for example, and to post the URL to me. I could fix the code to make it working and will post you the URL of the modified demo.